# I am creating a bill. I am taking quantity, price and dis(discount) from user and automatically calculating amount and total price

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My JavaScript is:

```
$('tbody').delegate('.qty,.price,.dis', 'keyup', function() {
  var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
  var qty = tr.find('.qty').val();
  var price = tr.find('.price').val();
  var dis = tr.find('.dis').val();
  var amount = (qty * price) - (qty * price * dis) / 100;
  tr.find('.amount').val(amount);
  total();
  var tax = tr.find('.tax').val();
  var g_total = total() + (total() * tax) / 100;
  tr.find('.g_total').val(g_total);
});
```

Now I want the user to be able to add sales tax and automatically give the grand total to the user. My JavaScript is working correctly until total but the rest not working.

Comment: What does not working look like?  Are there error messages?  Console messages?

Comment: @RobertWilliams As no one other than you has access to your code, posting the code for `total()` would help

Comment: Does `total()` return a value or not? It's used in both ways here.

Comment: And what version of jQuery are you using that implements [`delegate()`](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (deprecated in 3.0)?

Comment: @esqew total() returns values as the sum of amount. Since there are multiple values of amount().

Comment: @DavidThomas its v1.7.2 jQuery